# Add the ability to search for questions with less than a given number of answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, search

Sometimes I try to search for questions that meet certain criteria (rare tags, high score) that haven't been answered well, and try to answer them. However, currently I can only search for questions that have ZERO answers.

But that doesn't mean that a question with 1 or 2 answers has been answered well, especially if neither of those answers were accepted.

I would like to have a feature to be able to search for questions with fewer than a given number of answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `answers:1..2 hasaccepted:no` to your search to see questions with 1 or 2 answers, none accepted

[Advanced search help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Comment: You can accept an answer in 11 minutes.

Comment: only if you don't [move the goal posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)